# How to change keys in Objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I have a problem. I used to have an entity that had a `@id private String key` . But now I have to change that to a `@id private Long key`. Problem is Objectify wont let me. I get an

`IllegalStateException: Loaded Entity has name but com.XX.YYY.MyClass has no String @id`

So Im not sure what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not up on Objectify (so hopefuly someone who is can step in), but assume that Objectify is passing through the restriction that an Entity key must have exactly one of a name or an id. Once an Entity is created, the key is immutable.

The only ways to re-type a key are

1. Export the data, fix it up outside the datastore, then clear out the datastore and reload, or
2. Create and populate a parallel set of Entities of a new kind, migrating corresponding data from the old entity to the new.

In both case, you have to find and migrate references by hand.

Both of these involve careful work.

Comment: Thanks Dave, so what you'r saying in (2.) is that I create another Entity class which does basically the same thing and I migrate my existing entities to that one?

Comment: Yes. And then change any properties that pointed to the old entity to point to the new one.

Comment: I have the opposite situation. I need to change my entities long id's to String ids.  I have yet to do this, but it will take a lot of consideration as to all the indexes i have back to the original long ids.  makes me a little nervous because this is a live app.  How did it turn out for you @DaveW.Smith ?

Comment: It turned out fine, though I took the easy way out and pushed a 'disabled' version of the app (which showed a "we're undergoing maintenance" page), while the mapreduce that re-keyed the entities ran. When that was done, I pushed a new version.